# Prove that if m is a square integer then m is neither congruent to 2 modulo 5 nor congruent to 3 modulo 5

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove that if m is a square integer then m is neither congruent to 2 modulo 5 nor congruent to 3 modulo 5.

I've seen this problem done for modulo 4 and modulo 8 but this doesn't seem to work for me as the 2k doesn't square nicely to a 4. Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I'm very lost on this problem and where to start/how to prove. Case proof? Proof by contradiction? Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Consider squaring integers of the form $5k$, $5k \pm 1$, $5k \pm 2$.

Comment: $\!\bmod 5\!:\ x^2\in\{0,\pm1,\pm2\}^2 \equiv \{0,1,-1\}\ \ \ $

Answer (score 2):

Just square the integers mod $5$. 
We have
\begin{align}
0^2 &\equiv 0 \\
1^2 &\equiv 1 \\
2^2 &\equiv 4 \\
3^2 &\equiv 9 \equiv 4 \\
4^2 &\equiv 16 \equiv 1
\end{align}
Note that $2$ and $3$ don't appear on the right hand side of any of the above expressions.

Comment: What is the logical/mathematical justification for this? I'm trying to do this in a proof and though I understand that this works I don't know how to get to this

Comment: Have you seen that $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ has well-defined multiplication and addition? If this notation is unfamiliar to you, have you seen that modular arithmetic has well-defined multiplication and addition?

Comment: @user65909 $\bmod 5\!:\,$ every integer $n$ is congruent to its remainder $\,\bar n := n\bmod 5,\,$ where $\,0\le \bar n \le 4,\,$ thus  $\,n\equiv \bar n\,\Rightarrow\, n^2\equiv \bar n^2\,$ by the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). That's a rigorous justification using congruences.